# Select box from ecto users for belongs_to association

Tags: forms, phoenix-framework, ecto, belongs-to

Noob from rails trying to build a form with ecto `belongs_to` relationship. How do I add the `users` variable to the `available assigns`?

Controller:

```
  def new(conn, params) do
    changeset = Project.changeset(%Project{})
    users = Repo.all(from(u in User, order_by: u.email, select: {u.email, u.id}))
    Logger.debug "Controller: #{inspect users}"
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset, users: users)
  end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, @users, fn f -> %>   
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :user_id, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= Logger.debug "View 2: #{inspect @users}" %>
    <%= select f, :user_id, @users, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :user_id %>
  </div>
```

Error message:

```
(ArgumentError) assign @users not available in eex template.

Available assigns: [:action, :changeset]
```

Well great, I'm trying to add users to the the `available assigns`.

Answer (score 0):

Derp. This wouldn't have been correct in rails either. I had to add the variable to `new.html.eex`

```
<h2>New project</h2>

<%= render "form.html", changeset: @changeset,
                        action: project_path(@conn, :create),
                        users: @users %>

<%= link "Back", to: project_path(@conn, :index) %>
```